# Url request error when I use Umbraco backend

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I got 404 request, when I try to see one of my saved node.
The node has a multiple media picker with a lot of saved images.
If I check a short one, it's working.

```
http://localhost:57643/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Entity/GetByIds?ids=2118&ids=2114&ids=2120&ids=2122&ids=2121&type=Media
```

If I check the long one, I get the error:

```
http://localhost:57643/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Entity/GetByIds?ids=3516&ids=2116&ids=2114&ids=2115&ids=2117&ids=2118&ids=2119&ids=2120&ids=2122&ids=2121&ids=2123&ids=2124&ids=2125&ids=2126&ids=2127&ids=2128&ids=2131&ids=2130&ids=2129&ids=2132&ids=2133&ids=2134&ids=2159&ids=2160&ids=2161&ids=2158&ids=2157&ids=2156&ids=2153&ids=2155&ids=2154&ids=2150&ids=2151&ids=2152&ids=2146&ids=2145&ids=2144&ids=2148&ids=2149&ids=2147&ids=2141&ids=2142&ids=2143&ids=2140&ids=2139&ids=2138&ids=2135&ids=2136&ids=2137&ids=2056&ids=2057&ids=2060&ids=2059&ids=1353&ids=1354&ids=1355&ids=1358&ids=1357&ids=1356&ids=1359&ids=1360&ids=1361&ids=1364&ids=1363&ids=1362&ids=1365&ids=1366&ids=1367&ids=1370&ids=1369&ids=1368&ids=2644&ids=2645&ids=2646&ids=2649&ids=2648&ids=2647&ids=2650&ids=2651&ids=2652&ids=2655&ids=2654&ids=2653&ids=2656&ids=2657&ids=2658&ids=2661&ids=2660&ids=2659&ids=2662&ids=2663&ids=2664&ids=2667&ids=2666&ids=2665&ids=2668&ids=2669&ids=2670&ids=2671&ids=2672&ids=2673&ids=2676&ids=2675&ids=2674&ids=2677&ids=2678&ids=2679&ids=2682&ids=2681&ids=2680&ids=2683&ids=2685&ids=2688&ids=2687&ids=2686&ids=2689&ids=2690&ids=2691&ids=2694&ids=2693&ids=2692&ids=2698&ids=2695&ids=2696&ids=2697&ids=2700&ids=2699&ids=2701&ids=2702&ids=2703&ids=2706&ids=2705&ids=2704&ids=2707&ids=2708&ids=2709&ids=2644&ids=2645&ids=2646&ids=2649&ids=2648&ids=2647&ids=2650&ids=2651&ids=2652&ids=2655&ids=2654&ids=2653&ids=2656&ids=2658&ids=2657&ids=2661&ids=2660&ids=2659&ids=2662&ids=2663&ids=2664&ids=2667&ids=2666&ids=2665&ids=2668&ids=2669&ids=2670&ids=2673&ids=2672&ids=2671&ids=2674&ids=2675&ids=2676&ids=2679&ids=2678&ids=2677&ids=2680&ids=2681&ids=2682&ids=2685&ids=2684&ids=2683&ids=2686&ids=2687&ids=2688&ids=2691&ids=2690&ids=2689&ids=2692&ids=2693&ids=2694&ids=2697&ids=2696&ids=2695&ids=2698&ids=2699&ids=2700&ids=2703&ids=2702&ids=2701&ids=2704&ids=2705&ids=2706&ids=2709&ids=2708&ids=2707&ids=2972&ids=2973&ids=2974&ids=2977&ids=2976&ids=2975&ids=2978&ids=2979&ids=2980&ids=2983&ids=2982&ids=2981&ids=2984&ids=2985&ids=2986&ids=2989&ids=2988&ids=2987&ids=2990&ids=2991&ids=2992&ids=2995&ids=2994&ids=2993&ids=2996&ids=2997&ids=2998&ids=3001&ids=3000&ids=2999&ids=3002&ids=3003&ids=3004&ids=3007&ids=3006&ids=3005&ids=3008&ids=3009&ids=3010&ids=3013&ids=3012&ids=3011&ids=3014&ids=3015&ids=3016&ids=3017&ids=3018&ids=3019&type=Media
```

Is this because the request url is too long or something else?
If the length, how can I solve it?

Comment: That api request is 2329 characters.  Historically, the rule of thumb was to keep your urls lengths less that 2000 characters.

Seems like it would be returning a different response code (414) if it was too long.

Comment: Thank you, I thought something like this too.

Comment: Have you looked on issues.umbraco.org to see if anyone has posted an issue on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. You can change the query string limit in the web.config, I recommend limiting this to the specific path needed using the `<location>` tag:

```
<location path="umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Entity">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Adjust the values as required.

Also note that if you pick more than say 80-100 images, you'll reach the database limit of the column umbraco stores the data in (`dataNvarchar (nvarchar(500)`) in the table `cmsPropertyData`).

To overcome this, make umbraco store the value in the `dataNtext (ntext)` column instead, by updating the value of `dbType` from `Nvarchar` to `Ntext` in the row for the `Umbraco.MultipleMediaPicker` property editor in the table `cmsDataType`.